# Is it possible to add/wire a class based function to a class outside the class in python

Tags: python, qt, class, inheritance

Lets say I have a class:

```
class SomeClass(SomeSuper) :
    def __init__(self) :
        #some things
```

But just because the class is generated from somewhere like Qt-Designer .ui to .py I dont want to touch that class, yet I want to add a built in function that is overridden from the class's super class - say:

```
def closeEvent(self, e)
    #some things
```

Is there a way I can have:

```
a = SomeClass()
a.closeEvent()
```

where closeEvent() is outside the class somewhere else and is wired to the class?

Answer (score 1):

What about [*monkey patching*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the class?

```
SomeClass.closeEvent = closeEvent
```

Comment: Wow, from my Advance Python OOP tuturial, I nearly ignored it, I guess I have to go back and check it, thanks

Comment: @Temitayo this flexibility comes handy once in a while :)

Comment: By the way in the link provided by @MartijnPieters this is very well exaplained.